# How could I get the bound rect in which a substring will be drawn?

Tags: ios, nsstring

I want to get the box in which a certain substring of a NSString has been rendered in a UILabel (or a UITextView, if easier), taking into account the rect in which the entire NSString is drawn, pus the line break mode, font, etc. In OSX, in the additions, there is a method that returns that rect

```
- (NSRect)boundingRectWithSize:(NSSize)size options:(NSStringDrawingOptions)options attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributes
```

Does iOS have something similar? I checked the documentation but I didn't find anything. Is out there something similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think, this may help you

```
// Create some text view for example
_tv = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 10.0, 300.0f, 250.0f)];
_tv.text = @"dkjshfk shf kjhs fkj ewkjhf kwfwkj fhwk fwh fjkw hfjkhwe fkjwh";
_tv.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:24];
[self.view addSubview:_tv];
```

and this is what you looking for

```
- (void)someAction:(id)sender
{
    // Here is a frame of selected text in text view
    CGRect frame = [_tv firstRectForRange:_tv.selectedTextRange];

    // Mark selected text with yellow
    UIView *v = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    v.alpha = .8f;
    [_tv addSubview:v];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but this is not what I'm looking for. I want the rect of a substring of a string already rendered in a UILabel (or UITextView). I will edit the question to clarify.

Comment: Now, I see. Here is another one suggestion
CGRect frame = [_tv firstRectForRange:_tv.selectedTextRange];

Comment: Thanks, it works except if there is an Emoji, in that situation it doesn't returns the rect in the given range if it's after the Emoji. Do you have any clue of what is the problem? Maybe an encoding issue?

Comment: I have no problems with that. But, `The first rectangle in a range of text. You might use this rectangle to draw a correction rectangle. The “first” in the name refers the rectangle enclosing the **first** line when the range encompasses multiple lines of text.` So, we need second rect, thar present end position of selection. It's name `caretRectForPosition:` - return rect of caret, `CGRect frameEnd = [_tv caretRectForPosition:_tv.selectedTextRange.end];`. It remains to combine the two rectangles to get full rect of selection. Here is what I'm got [image link](http://goo.gl/TKPVJ)